# Android SharedPreference write = in value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am using SharedPreference to store  URLs.

These urls contains = , I try "" and '' but android still think is new key=value parameter, someone can help my?

Comment: Please paste your tried code

Comment: Please go thought guidelines of how to ask question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: show your line of code, it is not clear, what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this bro**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("yourKey","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pageSize=50");
    edit.commit();
```

**Retrive url like this**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
prefs.getString("yourKey","");
Log.d("URL",""+  prefs.getString("yourKey",""));
edit.commit();
```